# Calculation on joined data.table subset throws warning, but result is correct?

Tags: r, join, data.table

I want to subtract the values in the `dt_false` table from the matching rows in table `dt`. The result is correct, although I was wondering why the warning occured?

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id    = letters[1:15],
                 value = 1:15,
                 key   = "id")

dt_false <- data.table(id    = letters[6:20],
                       value = 6:20,
                       key   = "id")

# matching subset
dt[dt_false, nomatch=0]

# use nomatch = 0 to include only the matches
# use i.v1 to reference v1 from the i component
dt[dt_false, nomatch=0, value := value - i.value, ]

Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(dt, dt_false, `:=`(value, value - i.value), nomatch = 0) :
  Supplied 10 items to be assigned to 15 items of column 'value' (recycled leaving remainder of 5 items).
```

Comment: drop the `nomatch=0` argument, as everything that isn't matched won't be updated anyway. Just do `dt[dt_false, value := value - i.value]`

Comment: Seems to me that your expected behavior (assigning to the selected subset without complaint) is what should happen. The warning is easier to parse if you use, say `6:30` instead of `6:20`, in which case it says "Supplied 10 items to be assigned to 25 items", which makes it sound like it's assigning to `dt_false` (which has 25 items)...odd. Maybe it's just as David says and merge-assigns should just always be vanilla, `DT1[DT2,var:=stuff]` (without `nomatch`).

Comment: @DavidArenburg put your comment as  an answer so the question can be resolved.

Comment: @jangorecki I haven't investigated why `nomatch` has this effect and thus haven't posted an answer. As this is the real question here.